# What counts as a "large object" for Cherry Bomb?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

The description for Pin 039 (Cherry Bomb) states:

> Slam the target with an object from above. The object is chosen at random during charging. **Enemies struck by large objects will be knocked down.**

What exactly counts as a large object? I assume the red phone booth counts as large, but I'm unsure about items like the moped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out Cherry Bomb actually has *three* types of objects.

- **Small (no stun, 1x damage)**: Bicycle, floor sign
- **Large (stuns, 3.5x damage)**: Moped, phone booth
- **Extra large (stuns, 5x damage)**: Car

I tested this by equipping a mastered Cherry Bomb pin to a character with 100 attack, repeatedly fighting Mosh Grizzlies on Day 2, and recording the damage done. Each object fit within damage ranges of 32-34, 110-115, or 158-163.

[image: Spreadsheet of attack damage]